# Not Really Sure as to why I'm getting this amount of space in Overleaf

Tags: spacing

[image]

I am trying to build my Resume on Overleaf as of now. However, when I compile the code given in [this](https://gist.github.com/sd12832/e3f73562f71f99737ec00571e867746d) particular Gist, the sentence from line 117, is not emboldened at all.

```
Worked with \textbf{\href{http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~ashesh/}{TV Prabhakar}} to create \textbf{ZDrone},
```

Neither is the link, nor the word ZDrone emboldened. Not sure as to how I would go about changing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line 192 of the template there is an empty `\section{}`... remove this (I reported it that to the maintainer). It is there by mistake and causes this space.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to reduce spacing, you can use the `\vspace` command. The command is usually used to increase vertical spacing but allows the use of a negative value to decrease vertical spacing as well. E.g `\vspace{-0.2cm}` can be based above the `VOLUNTEERING` section command to move this section up. This isn't a particularly efficient solution but a quick one when you are in a rush.